# Variance-Covariance matrix in computational form in R

Tags: r, matrix, covariance

I'm working with a small, simple matrix in R to show the comparison between using the `(cov)` function and the mathematical computation of the variance-covariance matrix using the formula as `(1/n-1) * (t(x) %*% as.matrix(x) - n %*% Ybar * (t(Ybar)`

here is the data I'm working with for reference:

```
> dput(x)
structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Dim = c(6L, 3L))
```

When I run `x.cov <- cov(x)` it returns a 3 x 3 matrix with all values = 3.5

The code below is what I'm using to obtain the variance-covariance matrix using computational formula, but it is returning an error stating "in t(x) %*% as.matrix(x) - 6 %*% x.meanvec %*% t(x.meanvec) : non-conformable arrays"

```
one <- rep(1, 6)
x.meanvec <- (1/6) * t(one) %*% as.matrix(x)
matrix.t <- (1/5) * (t(x) %*% as.matrix(x) - 6 %*% x.meanvec %*% t(x.meanvec))
```

How can I fix the formula to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your formula and don't believe it is correct.

I'd do this:

```
(1/5) * (t(x - one %*% x.meanvec) %*% (x - one %*% x.meanvec))
```

Or more efficiently:

```
1/5 * crossprod(x - one %*% x.meanvec)
```